# Рассчитать высоту псевдоэлемента

Tags: html, css

Необходимо соединить псевдо-элементы, задать правильную высоту, чтобы не происходило такого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div.content {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  transition: .25s;
}

div.content h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'GilroyB', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

div.content div.horizontalLine {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 5%;
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #e74b4c;
}

div.content div.verticalLine {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30%;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 14%;
  background: #e74b4c;
}

div.content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'GilroyL', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.content p:before {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #e74b4c;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.content a.go {
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #e74b4c;
  font-family: 'GilroyL', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.content a.go:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 7.5%;
  background: #e74b4c;
}

div.content a.price {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #e74b4c;
  font-family: 'GilroyL', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.content a.price:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 27.5%;
  background: #e74b4c;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="offer">
            <div class="slider-offer owl-carousel">
                <div class="slide text-center">
                    <img src="img/Offer-Page/Business.png" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="verticalLine"></div>
                        <div class="horizontalLine"></div>
                        <h2>Бизнес решение</h2>
                        <p>Все что у "Старт"</p>
                        <p>Премиум поддержка, обслуживание</p>
                        <p>Яндекс Директ</p>
                        <p>SEO</p>
                        <a class="go" href="#">ПОЕХАЛИ!</a>
                        <a class="price" href="#">150.000р</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide text-center">
                    <img src="img/Offer-Page/Maybach.png" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="verticalLine"></div>
                        <div class="horizontalLine"></div>
                        <h2>Полный фарш</h2>
                        <p>Все что у Bisiness</p>
                        <p>Составление продажных скриптов, построение отдела продаж</p>
                        <p>Индивидуальные доработки</p>
                        <a class="go" href="#">ПОЕХАЛИ!</a>
                        <a class="price" href="#">300.000р</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide text-center">
                    <img src="img/Offer-Page/Renault.png" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="verticalLine"></div>
                        <div class="horizontalLine"></div>
                        <h2>Старт</h2>
                        <p>Полноценный сайт со всем функционалом</p>
                        <p>Обучение пользованием сайта</p>
                        <p>Хостинг</p>
                        <a class="go" href="#">ПОЕХАЛИ!</a>
                        <a class="price" href="#">50.000р</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать границы

```css
*,:before,:after{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.content{
  max-width:300px;
  border-left:2px solid red;
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
.content h2{
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  line-height:1;
  bottom:.5em;
}
.content h2:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  top:calc(50% - 1px);
  width:22px;
  border-top:2px solid red; 
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li:before{
  content:'- ';
  color:red;
}
.content__footer{
  position:relative;
  top:14px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.btn{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  line-height:1.5;
  padding:0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h2>Полный фарш</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Все что у Bisiness</li>
      <li>Составление продажных скриптов, построение отдела продаж</li>
      <li>Индивидуальные доработки</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content__footer">
      <a class="btn" href="#">ПОЕХАЛИ!</a>
      <a class="btn" href="#">300.000р</a>
    </div>
</div>
```